# Binding a DataGridView to an IBindingList that may contain zero elements

Tags: c#, list, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

Using C# WinForms in VS 2008 (.Net 3.5)

I am trying to bind a list, that may be empty, to a data grid.

If the list has elements, and AutoGenerateColumns is enabled, the data binds to the list and everything works fine.

However, if the list is empty, or if the list becomes empty (by deleting the last element) nothing at all is display, just the gray background.

If I create the columns manually, such as:

```
                if (m_DataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns == false)
                {
                    foreach (var pair in objData.PropertyDataTable
                        .Where(pair => pair.Value.IsNative == true
                                    && pair.Value.IsList == false))
                    {
                        string propertyName = pair.Key;
                        PropertyData propertyData = pair.Value;

                        if (propertyData.Type == typeof(bool))
                        {
                            var column = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn()
                            {
                                Name = propertyName,
                                HeaderText = propertyName,
                                DataPropertyName = propertyName,
                                ValueType = propertyData.Type,
                            };
                            m_DataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
                            {
                                Name = propertyName,
                                HeaderText = propertyName,
                                DataPropertyName = propertyName,
                                ValueType = propertyData.Type,
                            };
                            m_DataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

The columns appear, and I am able to add a new row, but the data is not actually bound, and no default values for the rows are populated like they normally are when the columns are auto generated.

When I leave the view and return, the added lines remain, but the data is not preserved.

Comparing the auto generated columns to the manually created columns in the debugger, the ***only*** property that is different between the two is the **IsDataBound** property on the DataGridViewColumn base class.

IsDataBound is set to true when AutoGenerateColumns is enabled, with one or more elements in the list, but is false is the list has zero initial elements, despite the DataPropertyName properties of the column being properly set.

**Is there any way to to bind an empty list to a data grid, and allow the users to add rows to the blank list, with everything properly bound?**

I've even tried adding an element to an empty list before binding, to have it auto generate and bind the columns... but as soon as the row is removed the columns disappear and the bindings are lost.

Other Implementation Details:

I am trying to bind a data source which is a custom List/Collection type that inherits from:

```
 - ICustomTypeDescriptor
 - IBindingList
 - ICancelAddNew
 - IList<T>
 - ICollection<T>
 - IEnumerable<T>
 - IList
 - ICollection
 - IEnumerable
```

The objects in the list are dynamic objects which inherit from **ICustomTypeDescriptor**, and map properties to values in a dictionary. The types are defined in an ObjectDefinition class that knows the available property info for the dynamic types (Property names, types, attributes, etc...)
Each list has a definition assigned to it, so that every object in the list has the same definition.

I don't think this matters, because as long as there is at least one element in the list everything is properly bound, and works fine.

Comment: Well, I know from my own work that IBindingList is the important one there.  Are you manually implementing IBindingList, or IBindingList<T>, on your collection Type?  On my own work, I also implement ICancelAddNew which is very useful.

Comment: The list of inherited types are listed above. I implement both IBindingList, and ICancelAddNew. Would IBindingList<T> fix the issue with the empty list?

Comment: Are you implementing the interfaces explicitly or do you inherit from BindingList<T>? I just tried this with a custom list that inherits from BindingList<T> and it works just fine for an empty list. I would suggest inheriting and overriding.

Comment: Also a little surprised that manually adding columns with the correct DataPropertyName specified doesn't work. I guess there is a lot of stuff going on with the BindingList under the covers.

Comment: I actually inherit from a class called UndoRedoList<Object>, which provides my necessary Undo/Redo & Collection features for tracking changes made to the list. So I can't inherit directly from BindingList<T>... The binding class is actually defined as such: `public class InstanceListData : UndoRedoList<Object>, ICustomTypeDescriptor, IBindingList, ICancelAddNew`, so apparently I'm missing something in my IBindingList implementation

Comment: BindingList<T> also includes `IRaiseItemChangedEvents` which I am not... is that related?

Comment: Check the link in my comment to Mark's answer - it took me less than a minute to get this working and it fixes the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For lists, it isn't ICustomTypeDescriptor that rules, but ITypedList. Implement this at the list level, and you can supply your properties at runtime as you see fit. Because this doesn't depend on any rows, it should work even for zero rows.

Comment: Wow nice answer! I was wondering how BindingList<T> did it's magic and as soon as I read this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404298.aspx detailing ITypedList and implemented the code on my own custom BindingList everything worked.

Comment: @DavidHall well, you need to watch out - it is more complex than that too :) if it can identify a likely type, via a public non-object indexer, `public SomeType this[int index] {get;}`, then if there is no ITypedList, it can use TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(SomeType)) - which means that TypeDescriptionProvider can *also* get a chance to interfere.

Comment: @Josh see comment above too, just for extra options

Comment: Also, if you choose Marc's way (the easiest and the best) you need typed indexer to be implicit. I.e. you must implement IList<> interface implicitly. If you have typed indexer as explicit interface implementation, such as `T IList<T>.this[int index]`, it won't work.